# Can I get the unmodified source html code of an angular component inside?

Tags: angular

Is it possible to get the original (unmodified) source HTML code of an angular components innerHTML?

If one injects ElementRef and uses `this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML` in `ngOnInit` method, angular already has added classes, attributes, comments to the code.